# RabbitMQ broadcast events to all consumers

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp

Is possible to use `topic` exchange as true event notification system?

I've created `topic` exchange on given exchange named as `Cherry`. I've got one publisher at routing key `cherry.user.created` and many consumers with same routing key, but when I publish an event only one of consumers consume an event. I thought that topic can be used as "real event broadcasting" - every consumer gets notified when given event happened, but right now only one consumer consume an event and other consumers do not know about created event...

Comment: Most likely all your consumers use the same queue. If that is not so - provide more details about how exactly you publish and consume.

Comment: Year, you're right, I've used same queues, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify my comment about queues. In rabbitmq, if multiple consumers use the same queue - message delivered to that queue is always dispatched in round-robin manner, no matter what. So when you subscribe to topic exchange, best way is to declare new queue for each consumer (with any name, or better random generated by rabbit itself) and use target routing key (`cherry.user.created`) to bind those queues to exchange.